# Why can't I get my background-image responsive?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm actually stuck to develop a two-column responsive website. I cannot get my background-image to be responsive and I don't know if my structure is correct.
My first column is called `sidebar` and the second one - `main-content`.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <section class="sidebar">
        <nav>
            <div id="logo" class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1>Coffee Mug</h1></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>
    <section class="main-content">
        <header class="container-fluid">
        </header>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 .sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100% !important;
    background-color: #93AF79 !important;
}

#logo
{
    margin: 80px 100px;
}

#navbar ul li
{
    text-align: center;
}

#main-content
{
    width: 85%;
}

header
{
    background: url("Coffee_mug2.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    height: 600px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide additional details? either way seems you used 85% instead of 75%m alternatively the sidebar is 25% instead of 15%

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. Actually my background-image doesn't resize properly according to screen ratio. Normally I'm using .img-fluid for any images in my HTML code but I don't know how to make it work for background and CSS. Properties max-width: 100% and height: auto seem to have no effect.

Comment: How would you like the background image to behave? It's has a very wide aspect ratio, and with `background-size: cover` you tell it to always fill out the whole container, so zoom in until the `height: 600px` is fully covered by the background image.
`background-size: contain` on the other hand would always show the full image, but reducing the height of course when the viewport gets narrower

Comment: Hi, to make things clearer, I'd like to achieve something like this: http://www.fleuriste-jardin-de-cecilia.fr/#

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, so you mean like this?

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100% !important;
  background-color: #93AF79 !important;
}

#logo {
  margin: 80px 100px;
}

#navbar ul li {
  text-align: center;
}

#main-content {
  width: 75%;
}

header {
  background: url("https://sd-1.archive-host.com/membres/images/210138792344645661/Coffee_mug2.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  height: 600px;
}

main {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<section class="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <div id="logo" class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <h1>Coffee Mug</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
<section class="main-content">
  <header class="container-fluid"></header>
  <main>content content content</main>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a misuse of the [background shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), the following change should get it done for you:

```
header{
    background: no-repeat url("https://sd-1.archive-host.com/membres/images/210138792344645661/Coffee_mug2.png") ;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everybody! It looks like it was the 'cover' value that was wrong. I don't know how I could have missed it!

Comment: As long as it works now. I see that you're rather new in this site, in order to let other know that this question is answered you can mark it like it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)